Action bar is not being hidden
So i am making a mobile app and in my main menu the actionbar/tittle bar is still showing after many atempts to hide it.
I tried to change the themes witch did not work , i tried to hide it in the homefragment code and did the same in ProfileFragment , i did try to solve it inside the activity that hosts the fragments and still nothing . Im kinda lost so i need help solving this .
HomeFragment:
package com.example.ambicheck.ui.home;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.ambicheck.CreateRoomActivity;
import com.example.ambicheck.DataClass;
import com.example.ambicheck.MyAdapter;
import com.example.ambicheck.R;
import com.example.ambicheck.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding;
import com.example.ambicheck.recyclerViewMain;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentHomeBinding binding;
    private TextView todasTextView;
    private TextView criarDivisaoTextView;
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<DataClass> dataList;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    DataClass androidData;
    TextView olaTextView;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getActionBar() != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        }

        binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        todasTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.todas);
        olaTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.Ola);
        criarDivisaoTextView = root.findViewById(R.id.criarDivisao);

        todasTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), recyclerViewMain.class));
            }
        });

        criarDivisaoTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CreateRoomActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        recyclerView = root.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), dataList, R.layout.recycler_item);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {
            String name = user.getDisplayName();
            String email = user.getEmail();
            olaTextView.setText("Olá, " + name + " ");
        }

        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Rooms");
        dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
                if (user != null) {
                    String userId = user.getUid();
                    dataList.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot roomSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String id = roomSnapshot.getKey(); // Get the room's ID from the snapshot
                        String roomName = roomSnapshot.child("roomName").getValue(String.class); // Get the room's name
                        Integer ratingValue = roomSnapshot.child("rating").getValue(Integer.class); // Get the room's rating
                        int rating = ratingValue != null ? ratingValue : 0; // If the rating is null, default to 0
                        String description = roomSnapshot.child("description").getValue(String.class); // Get the room's description
                        String imageUrl = roomSnapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue(String.class); // Get the room's image URL
                        String roomUserId = roomSnapshot.child("userId").getValue(String.class); // Get the user ID associated with the room

                        if (userId.equals(roomUserId)) { // Only add the room to the dataList if the user ID matches
                            DataClass roomData = new DataClass(id, roomName, rating, description, imageUrl,userId); // Create a new DataClass object with the retrieved data
                            dataList.add(roomData); // Add the new DataClass object to the dataList
                        }
                    }
                    // Notify the adapter of the change
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                // Trate o erro
            }
        });

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }
}

ProfileFragment:
package com.example.ambicheck.ui.perfil;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.example.ambicheck.Activity_Definicoes;
import com.example.ambicheck.Activity_GestaoF;
import com.example.ambicheck.Activity_Login;
import com.example.ambicheck.Activity_Perfil;
import com.example.ambicheck.Activity_ServicoCloud;
import com.example.ambicheck.R;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;

import io.getstream.avatarview.AvatarView;

public class PerfilFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
    private AvatarView avatarView;
    private Button btnLogout;
    private Button definicoesButton;
    private Button gestaoFamiliasButton;
    private TextView nomeUtilizador;
    private TextView emailTextview;
    private ImageView profileImageView;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private Uri selectedImageUri;
    private Context mContext;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);
        mContext = getActivity();
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        btnLogout = view.findViewById(R.id.buttonLogout);
        definicoesButton = view.findViewById(R.id.definicoes);
        gestaoFamiliasButton = view.findViewById(R.id.GestaoFamilias);
        avatarView = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar_view);
        nomeUtilizador = view.findViewById(R.id.nomeUtilizador);
        profileImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profileImageView);
        emailTextview = view.findViewById(R.id.emailTextview);

        // Fetch and display profile image
        fetchAndDisplayProfileImage();

        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userName = currentUser.getDisplayName();
            String userEmail = currentUser.getEmail();

            nomeUtilizador.setText(userName);
            emailTextview.setText(userEmail);
        }
        if (getActivity() != null && getActivity().getActionBar() != null) {
            getActivity().getActionBar().hide();
        }

        profileImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);
            }
        });

        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        definicoesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_Definicoes.class));
            }
        });

        gestaoFamiliasButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), Activity_GestaoF.class));
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        if (selectedImageUri != null) {
            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();
            StorageReference profileImagesRef = storageRef.child("profile_images/" + FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid() + ".jpg");

            profileImagesRef.putFile(selectedImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(taskSnapshot -> {
                        profileImagesRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(uri -> {
                            String imageURL = uri.toString();
                            saveImageURLToDatabase(imageURL);
                        });
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to upload image to Firebase Storage", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });
        }
    }

    private void saveImageURLToDatabase(String imageURL) {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();
            DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId);
            userRef.child("imagemPerfil").setValue(imageURL)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
                        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageURL).into(profileImageView);
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Failed to save image URL to database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    });
        }
    }

    private void fetchAndDisplayProfileImage() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        if (currentUser != null) {
            String userId = currentUser.getUid();
            DatabaseReference userRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(userId);
            userRef.child("imagemPerfil").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String imageURL = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                    if (imageURL != null && !imageURL.isEmpty()) {
                        Glide.with(mContext).load(imageURL).into(profileImageView);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    // Handle error
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

Themes:
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Theme.noActionBar.Ambicheck" parent="Theme.Material3.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>


</resources>

Manifest:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.noActionBar.Ambicheck"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".GroupDetailActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateRoomActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Notifications"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GroupMembersActivity"
            android:exported="false" /> <!-- File: AndroidManifest.xml -->
        <activity
            android:name=".QRCodeScannerActivity"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_CreacaoGrupos"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_QRcode"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_PerfilUser"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_ServicoCloud"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_GestaoF"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Definicoes"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_notificacoes"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Perfil"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_intro"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".recyclerViewMain" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_menu"
            android:exported="false"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_menu"
            tools:ignore="DuplicateActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Actitvity_RecuperarConta"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Registrar"
            android:exported="false" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Login"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>

Actitivy_menu:
package com.example.ambicheck;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.example.ambicheck.databinding.ActivityMenuBinding;
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class Activity_menu extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().hide();
        }

        ActivityMenuBinding binding = ActivityMenuBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        // Find the NavHostFragment
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_menu2);

        // Get the NavController
        assert navHostFragment != null;
        NavController navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        // Find the BottomNavigationView
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);

        // Setup navigation with NavController
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }
}```




have you consulted Google for Developers (https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/layout/immersive) ?

Try applying that created theme to your activity, not to the application

Instead of getActionBar(), use getSupportActionBar(). It is required when you are extending your activity with AppCompatActivity.
